# Rails minitest & CurrentAttributes, could not find table 'currents'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm working on a Rails 7 app, I'm relatively new to Rails testing. Using the default minitest. I'm having some troubles getting my tests to pass / run. When running `rails test` I'm currently getting the following error:

```
Error:
CompanyTest#test_Should_have_a_unique_name:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'currents'
```

I don't have ny table called `Current` (or `currents`) in the app. I'm however having a model class inheriting from `CurrentAttributes`:

```
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :company
end
```

I'm getting it's this class that is causing the error when I run `rails test`. Any ideas on what I'm potentially missing?

One example of a failing test (currently getting 60 errors, so shouldn't be specific to a specific test case):

```
test "should have a unique name" do
  company_b = @company.dup
  assert_not company_b.valid?
end
```

**Adding full trace here**

```
Error:
CompanyTest#test_Should_have_a_unique_name:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'currents'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord- 7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:387:in `table_structure'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord- 7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:116:in   `columns'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:117:in `block in columns'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:116:in `fetch'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:116:in `columns'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:125:in `block in columns_hash'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:124:in `fetch'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:124:in `columns_hash'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:472:in `build_fixture_sql'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:142:in `block (2 levels) in build_fixture_statements'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:142:in `map'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:142:in `block in build_fixture_statements'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:140:in `each'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:140:in `flat_map'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:140:in `build_fixture_statements'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:402:in `insert_fixtures_set'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:630:in `block in insert'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:621:in `each'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:621:in `insert'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:607:in `read_and_insert'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:567:in `create_fixtures'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:275:in `load_fixtures'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:125:in `setup_fixtures'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.4/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:10:in `before_setup'
/Users/<name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.4/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:40:in `before_setup'
```

Comment: The stack trace feels to me like there are fixtures for the `Current` class. What doesn't make much sense because a database table does not back that class. Would you mind double-checking that?

Comment: @spickermann Yeah, I don't have any table for `Current`.

Comment: But do you have a fixtures file for `Current`?

Comment: @spickermann Oh, you were right, I had a `currents yml` file. Removing that file the error disappeared.